# Profiteering and corruption by Hajj tour operators due to limited quota

Tags: hajj

If one is convinced that Hajj tour operators are corrupt due to charging exorbitant amounts from intended pilgrims because of limited quota, then:

**Is it discouraged to apply for Hajj from such tour operators?**

I see following potential problems with applying to such operators;

- You are depriving other's from going to Hajj.
- You are encouraging such practices.

Comment: I have rephrased your question in order for it to conform to islam.SE Q/A format. If you are unhappy with this edit, you can rollback to previous version, but if you do so, your question will probably closed as being off-topic.

Comment: If a muslim would actively exploit other, by avoiding to fulfill their Hajj, wouldn't he go into the deepest Hell? It seems to me an exceptional crime. But, I don't think the corruption would be worse here as in Saudi Arabia anywhere. They really don't have too much place more.

Comment: They've inserted billions of dollars into it, they've built a 2million city in the desert, half of the worlds planes are transferring pilgrims for Dhul'Hijjah, but still only around a fifth of the muslim men can do the hajj.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as you mentioned, nowadays it could be seen that perhaps some parts (Hajj tour operators) are doing it, but in regard to your matter, I can mention some related points, such as:

- Nevertheless we should pay attention that doing Haj is considered as
  a Wajib (mandatory) practice for Muslims, consequently we should do
  it anyhow (according to its conditions)
- strive to solve the mentioned matter as much as we can, for example
  by protesting (I mean speaking) to the related persons in charges or
  ...
- another significant issue is that it is better that the persons who
  have gone to Haj once, then allow others go it.

On the whole, nevertheless, we should notice that Haj is counted as a Wajib act, then it ought to be done for Muslims anyway.